# Jquery AjaxStop not firing while AjaxStart does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, triggers

I was experiencing APIs and found myself block on something.

I have thet Jquery function that fetch data from an api, and in order to not get a "reposition" effect, I need the function to wait for all the call to be made before triggering another function that will places all the api date in place.

I tried using AjaxStart and AjaxStop, but while the first one works perfectly, the second one doesn't, and I can't figure out why...

The app i'm building is quite big, So I made a codePen to simplify my question :

HTML:

```
<div id="button"></div>
<div id='locationbox'>
  <span id='city'>Get the country</span>
  <img id = "countryimg" src="">
  <div id='searching'> searching...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#button{
  height : 150px;
  width : 150px;
  border : 5px solid black;
  border-radius : 50%;  
  position : absolute;
  top : 45%;
  left : 45%;
}
#locationbox{
  text-align : center;
  width : 300px;
  position : absolute;
  top : 25%;
  left : 38.5%;

}
```

JavaScript :

```
$("#button").on('click',function(){
  getCity();

});

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $("#city").html("fetching data");

});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $("#searching").html("Success")    
});

function getCity(){
$.ajax({
  datatype : "json",
  contentType : "application/json",
  type : "GET",
  url : "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?",
  data : {
    format:"json",
    lat :"50.8503",
    lon : "4.3517",
    zoom:"18",
    adressdetails:"1"
  },
  success : function(quote){
    var city = quote.address.city;
    var country = quote.address.country
    var countryCode = quote.address.country_code.toUpperCase()
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city + " , " + country;
    document.getElementById("countryimg").src = "http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/" + countryCode + ".png";
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country;
  },
  error : document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "error!"
});
};
```

As you can see in [this code pen](https://codepen.io/Hadrienallemon/pen/GQmdpQ) while the AjaxStart triggers, the AjaxStop won't. Thanks for reading and thanks you all for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of an error in your success code block. Because of this error, your ajaxStop does not execute.

Remove the line `document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country;` since there is no element in the document with that id. Else, add an element with id `country`

Check the working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyjMOQ

Comment: Oh well, it was simple enough :D Thanks a lot !